# Jittery Character Controller

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a character which uses the camera as a frame of reference to know in which direction it has to move

```
movement = Quaternion.AngleAxis(sharpCam.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up) * movement;
```

This normally works ok but when i try and add smoothing to my camera the player becomes all jittery (from what i assume is the code above)

this is my cam smoothing code:

```
    if (rotProg < 1 && rotProg >= 0)
    {
        rotProg += Time.deltaTime * 15;
        Quaternion rotStart = transform.rotation;
        rotEnd = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
        rot = Quaternion.Lerp(rotStart, rotEnd, rotProg);
    }

    Vector3 pos = rot * new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -walkDist) + Target.position;
    pos.y += height;
    transform.rotation = rot;
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, pos, ref velocity, smoothTime);
```

[Gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM7I6.jpg)

Comment: You would be better off using `Vector3.Lerp` in this situation and I think that would resolve your issue going by the code you provided,

Comment: That seemed to have made it slightly better but it is still visible especially when jumping.

Comment: Do you have any other scripts controlling any aspect of the player and / or camera position/rotation?

Comment: Nope, i think that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, the issue was the movement code for the character and the code for the gravity was in Fixed Update instead of Update.